# Find multiple elements in web view with espresso

Tags: android, xpath, webview, android-webview, android-espresso

I'm testing a hybrid app, where each view has a web view.
In one of these web views I have a list of elements with the same attribute. They have the same xpath locator that is something like:

```
//h4[contains(@data-role, 'product-name')]
```

I want to create a list of these elements and iterate through them, count them, get their attributes.

In the documentation, I found two similar methods:

```
findElement(locator, value)
```

and

```
findMultipleElements(locator, value)
```

Though it's totally unclear to me how to use it. I tried to find examples on it but with no success.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: I don't know whether it's more fantastic that not a single line of documentation or any example exist or 
that `findMultipleElements` returns `Atom<List<ElementReference>>` instead of `List<Atom<ElementReference>>` so it can't be used for anything at all.

Comment: See my answer, I found a way to convert `Atom<List<ElementReference>>` into `List<ElementReference>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that I have found.

@kaqqao is right that `findMultipleItems` call returns `Atom<List<ElementReference>>` that is not usable with `onWebView()` because there you have only `withElement()` that accepts either `Atom<ElementReference>` or just `ElementReference`

What you can do though is perform your action that find multiple items and just get results from your Atom. This is how it works internally if you check the source of `doEval` method inside Web.java for espresso.

```
val elements = with(AtomAction(findMultipleElements(
                Locator.XPATH,
                "YOUR_COMPLEX_XPATH"
        ), null, null)) {
            onView(ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(WebView::class.java)).perform(this)
            this.get()
        }
```

This code will give you `List<ElementMatcher>`.

Then just run it as

```
elements.forEach {          
  onWebView().forceJavascriptEnabled().withElement(it).perform(webClick())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try something like that? Since what you should care about is really the ElementReference and you can iterate the lsit returned from findMultipleElements with simple for/foreach statement:

```
yourList = findMultipleElements(locator, value);
yourList.size(); //this will get you the count of found elements with that locator
for(Atom<ElementReference> item : yourList ){
    item.getAttribute...
    //and whatever you want
}
```