# how to access list of <div> tag using espresso web?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have need to automate webview using espresso web in my Android application.There are list of components in  Tag eg(Item1 in  1st position and Item2 in 2nd Position.I tried Xpath along with findMultipleElements(Locator,string) to acess individual item  but no luck.
How to access individual atom to validate individual component data?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610485/find-multiple-elements-in-web-view-with-espresso/63721046#63721046 for a possible answer